# How to extract seasonal trends from Prophet

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I have been using Prophet from Facebook and so far it has been produced some great results.

Having looked in the docs and googling, there doesn't seem to be an automatic way to extract the seasonal trends from a model as a dataframe or a dict, e.g.:

```py
weekly_trends = { 1 : monday_trend, 2 : tuesday_trend, ... , 7 : sunday_trend } 

yearly_trends = { 1 : day_1_trend, 2 : day_2_trend, ... , 365 : day_365_trend }
```

Currently I can extract these out using a more manual way but was just wondering if I had missed something more elegant?

Comment: what is your more manual way?

Comment: Just by filtering on a whole calendar year, giving me a map of day num in year to the respective seasonal component. Then doing the same for weekly by just selecting the first full week of the year, then I have a map of day num in week to weekly component

Answer (score 9):

The trained model dataframe has all the seasonal, trend and holidays information. - take a look at its columns. Here's how to look into it in Python:

```
m = Prophet()
m.fit(ts)
future = m.make_future_dataframe()
forecast = m.predict(future)
print(forecast['weekly'])
```

Take any 7 days out of that series. That will give you the scale of the additive weekly adjustment for each weekday. Similar for the yearly seasonality.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is essentially what I'm doing now but it isn't as elegant as I had hoped, maybe they will fix this in future

Comment: yep, sorry, missed your comment to the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can specify *daily*, *weekly*, and *yearly* seasonality during model fit

```
    m = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.01, weekly_seasonality=False, holidays=holidays, interval_width=0.90, yearly_seasonality=True, mcmc_samples=300)
    m.add_seasonality(name='weekly', period=7, fourier_order=3)
    m.add_seasonality(name='monthly', period=30.5, fourier_order=8)
    m.fit(X)
```

Comment: this doesn't actually let you extract out the seasonal values, it just models with these seasonal components. I'm interested in elegantly extracting out the components, not in the modelling itself

Answer (score -1):

When fitting the model, `Prophet` will save an `OrderedDict` that contains the seasonality.

You can retrieve them using `m.seasonalities`.

Example:

```py
m = Prophet()
m.fit(ts)
print(m.seasonalities)
```

Will output something like this:

```json
{
  "yearly": {
    "period": 365.25,
    "fourier_order": 10,
    "prior_scale": 10,
    "mode": "additive",
    "condition_name": null
  },
  "weekly": {
    "period": 7,
    "fourier_order": 3,
    "prior_scale": 10,
    "mode": "additive",
    "condition_name": null
  }
}
```

Than you can iterate the key (yearly, weekly, daily) and get the number of period or the other useful information.